# ToC heading pushed down with "tocloft"

Tags: tocloft, small-caps

ToC heading is pushed down when using `tocloft` package – even without any commands written. Leaving it out puts things back in place. Also I noticed the smaller the `\document[font-size]`, the bigger disposition of ToC heading. Is there an elegant way to bring the heading where it should be?

```
\documentclass[oneside, 10pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand\cftchapfont{\scshape}
\renewcommand\cftchappagefont{\scshape}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter{Thank you}
This is just great :)

\end{document}
```

[image: Pages of ToC and 1st Chapter]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Did you try `\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}`?

Comment: @egreg Thank you for fast and warm welcome :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=%2Btitles+%2Btocloft+is%3Aanswer you'll be presented with 172 results: the `tocloft` package, by default, redesigns the format of the chapter headers for the table of contents, list of tables and list of figures. However, I couldn't find a precise duplicate.

Fortunately, it provides the `titles` option that avoids this customization.

```
\documentclass[oneside, 10pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\renewcommand\cftchapfont{\scshape}
\renewcommand\cftchappagefont{\scshape}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter{Thank you}
This is just great :)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to change the font of the chapter entries in TOC with a KOMA-Script class you could use

```
\setkomafont{chapterentry}{\scshape}
```

So there is no need to use `tocloft` together with `scrbook`.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[oneside, 10pt]{scrbook}

\setkomafont{chapterentry}{\scshape}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\chapter{Thank you}
This is just great :)
\end{document}
```